# Show that $A = \{(3x,y)~|~ x,y \in Z\}$ is a maximal ideal of $Z \oplus Z$.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

So i know the question has been answered already but the answer uses isomorphisms that I have not been taught. I was wondering if you can show the factor group is a field directly. Let us assume that $A$ is in fact an ideal. Then we look at the factor group $(Z \oplus Z)/A$ and try to show it is a field. Let us take an arbitrary element of the factor group $(a,b)+A$. We want to show we have a multiplicative inverse so $(a,b)*(c,d)+A=(1,1)+A$ but I don't see a solution here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Show it's the kernel of a homomorphism to the field $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I want to find an inverse to an aribtrary element and i was wondering how that is done in this case.

Comment: There are only three elements, and one is the zero element, so you need only find inverses for two of them.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $(2a,b)$ and $(a,b)$ right?  some of them are still zero elements but i still dont see the solution.